# SSH & ping works between VMs, telnet and curl doesn't

Tags: curl, nginx, tcp, centos, chef-infra

I have VMWare Fusion with two VMs running CentOS 6.7, I'm trying to deploy Chef on them (server & workstation). Ping and ssh between two VMs work fine, but when I go `knife client list` it says that it can't find route to host. Curl and telnet don't work either. Some info: VMWare Fusion running on OS X Yosemite, firewall disabled, network settings on both VMs are "share with my Mac". `nestat -puntal | grep nginx` on server yields:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9680                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1091/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1091/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9683                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1091/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1091/nginx
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:5A:9E:EE
          inet addr:172.16.20.131  Bcast:172.16.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe5a:9eee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:29039 (28.3 KiB)  TX bytes:14305 (13.9 KiB)
```

errors:

```
[root@chefworkstation ~]# knife client list
ERROR: Errno::EHOSTUNREACH: No route to host - connect(2) for "chefsrv1" port 443

[root@chefworkstation ~]# curl chefsrv1
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

[root@chefworkstation ~]# ping chefsrv1
PING chefsrv1.localdomain (172.16.20.131) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.20.131: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.685 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.20.131: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.335 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.20.131: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.319 ms
```

Comment: `service iptables status`?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a brute force solution but I disabled `iptable_filter` module and disabled `selinux`. Works now.